# delete from select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to delete the resulted rows from the following SELECT query

```
select customer_ID, order_ID, t1, t2 
from web_order, items_table as a, items_table as b
  where (web_order.t1 = a.item_name and a.quantity) 
   and (web_order.t2 =  b.item_name and b.quantity)
   and ((a.quantity < b.quantity));
```

This is my DELETE query

```
delete from web_order where customer_ID in
(select customer_ID, order_ID, t1, t2 
 from web_order, items_table as a, items_table as b
   where (web_order.t1 = a.item_name and a.quantity) 
     and (web_order.t2 = b.item_name and b.quantity)
     and ((a.quantity < b.quantity)));
```

but I am getting this error

```
ERROR 1241 (21000): Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Comment: You want to get rid of rows where `customer_ID`--a single column--`is in` a query containing four columns. Don't do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot select from the table that you're deleting from in your delete statement - that would be like trying to add/remove items from a collection as you're iterating over it.

Here's the official statement from the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html):

> **Subqueries**
>
> You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a
>   subquery.

You will need to use your select statement to insert the customer_ID values into a temp table, then select from the temp table in your delete.

So, it would look something like this (I'm assuming Customer_ID is an INT column in your web_order table):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE CustomerIDs (Customer_ID INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO CustomerIDs 
select customer_ID from web_order, items_table as a, items_table as b
 where (web_order.t1 = a.item_name and a.quantity) 
 and (web_order.t2 = b.item_name and b.quantity)
 and ((a.quantity < b.quantity))

DELETE FROM web_order WHERE Customer_ID IN (SELECT Customer_ID FROM CustomerIDs)

DROP TABLE CustomerIDs
```

Comment: it works! thank you so much i really appreciate your help